# Verify the date of birth taken as user input with the value stored in nested dictionary in a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to verify date of birth taken from user and comparing it with the value stored in dictionary database. But it is not verifying the value even if I have entered the right value of date of birth. Here is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict



accountDetails = [
    {"FirtsName": "JOHN", "LastName": "DENIS","date of Birth": "01-06-1992", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
    {"FirtsName": "AKASH", "LastName": "MAHAJAN", "date of Birth": "04-02-1995","Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
    {"FirtsName": "AMAN", "LastName": "RANA","date of Birth": "11-04-1996", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
    {"FirtsName": "ANKUR", "LastName": "JAIN","date of Birth": "21-05-1990", "Account Number": "432524352345234", "Account Balance": "50000"},
]


d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for item in accountDetails:
    d[item['FirtsName']][item['LastName']][item['date of Birth']] = item

# get valid first name
while True:
    first_name_input = input('Enter First Name:\n').upper()
    if first_name_input in d:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter valid First Name')

# get valid last name
while True:
    last_name_input = input('Enter Last Name:\n').upper()
    if last_name_input in d[first_name_input]:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter valid Last Name')
                         # get valid last name
while True:
    dob_input = input('Enter dob:\n')
    if  dob_input in d[first_name_input]:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter valid dob')


print(d[first_name_input][last_name_input])
```

The user has put the value as-04-02-1995

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: I get all the details stored in database related the values user has entered.

Comment: Yea I am understanding that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test versus keys in the *second* level of your nested dictionary:

```
while True:
    dob_input = input('Enter dob:\n')
    if dob_input in d[first_name_input][last_name_input]:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter valid dob')
```

This becomes clear when you `print` the structure of the nested dictionary you have created:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'AKASH': defaultdict(dict,
                         {'MAHAJAN': {'04-02-1995': {'Account Balance': '50000',
                            'Account Number': '432524352345234',
                            'FirtsName': 'AKASH',
                            'LastName': 'MAHAJAN',
                            'date of Birth': '04-02-1995'}}}),
             ...
             'JOHN': defaultdict(dict,
                         {'DENIS': {'01-06-1992': {'Account Balance': '50000',
                            'Account Number': '432524352345234',
                            'FirtsName': 'JOHN',
                            'LastName': 'DENIS',
                            'date of Birth': '01-06-1992'}}})})
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your solution, Can you please explain as to how I must edit my code to get your solution?

Comment: See this: `d[first_name_input][last_name_input]`. You have `dob_input in d[first_name_input]`.

Comment: @Rohn. Please start by reading the solution very carefully. It has a nice explanation that really has everything you need once you take the time to understand.